# I don't know why my picture isn't floating to the center

Tags: css, html

I need my image in the center but it's not for some reason.
 My HTML code:

```
<div class="face-img">
    <img id="profile-img" src="http://host2post.com/server13/photos/jI7X5kXAIEk_4M~/1680x1050-lake-tahoe-california-desktop-wallpaper-background.jpg" />
</div>
```

And my CSS code:

```
.face-img{
  display: inline-block;
}
#profile-img{
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.face-img #profile-img{
    float: center;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BBaughn/e941djLg/

Comment: `float:center` do not exists. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp

Answer (score 1):

As [MDN states](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align), the `text-align` property needs to be on the parent element:

> The [`text-align` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align) describes how inline content like text is aligned **in its parent block element**. text-align does not control the alignment of block elements itself, only their inline content.

Since the `img` element is `inline` by default, `text-align: center` will effectively center the child `img` element within the parent.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/ag1zphw8/)

In your case you would just need to remove `display: inline-block` since this was causing the parent to have a ["shrink to fit" width](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#float-width) (which means that the parent element was the same width as the child, thus, no centering is visible).

```
.face-img {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Also, `center` isn't a valid value for the [`float` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float).

Comment: @BrendonBaughn Well, it works in the one I linked to - http://jsfiddle.net/ag1zphw8/

Comment: I had to get rid of the "display: inline-block" lol thank you

Comment: @BrendonBaughn Yea.. I said that in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `display: inline-block` and add `text-align: center` to `face-img` class.

Answer (score 0):

some simplified code, using the margin auto solution. it assumes you don't need the other stuff I omitted..

Using *auto* on the left and right margins of the img the pic is centered in the middle of the page. margin: 0 auto 0 auto;

fiddle example

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/dfo4ku4a/1/

css

```
.profile-img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    height: 200px;    width: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

html

```
<img class="profile-img" src="">
```

Answer (score 0):

Following css works:

```
.face-img {
  text-align: center;
}

#profile-img {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works:

```
.face-img{
   width:200px;
   margin-left:auto;
   margin-right:auto;
}
#profile-img{
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;  
}
```

Set the width of the div and set the left and right margins to auto.